# Make left bar button's title of navigation item the same as previous view's title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationitem, pushviewcontroller

In my **1st VC(postVC)**, I have below code to set navigation bar title varied to username:

```
// Set nav bar items.
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@'s Posts",[userPassed username]];
self.navigationItem.title = title;
```

However, there is a little problem here that when I call **2nd VC(detailVC)** by this method (push VC), the left bar button item's title in the **2nd VC** is shown "back" but I expect its title to follow the title in previous VC(**1st VC**).

```
- (void) didSelectItemFromCollectionView:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *cellData = [notification object];
    if (cellData)
    {
        if (!self.detailViewController)
        {
            self.detailViewController = [[PAWUserPostsDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PAWUserPostsDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        }
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = cellData;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

If I change

```
 self.navigationItem.title = @"test";
```

it works as expected. In **2nd VC**, left bar button item's title is shown "test" as I want.
So, to be clear, my question is how to make left bar button item's title follow the title of previous VC which is varied by username.

Comment: then pass your data from 1st VC to 2VC while push VC.

Comment: @user1478 I also thought of this idea. I passed on username to 2nd VC and set navigation bar item in there but it didn't work. Or perhaps I misunderstand your comment. Please advise.

Comment: @ SanitLee see my answer post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postVC.h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString*title;
```

In postVC.m file

```
title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@'s Posts",[userPassed username]];
self.navigationItem.title = title;
self.detailViewController.newtitle=self.title; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
```

In detailVC.h file

```
  @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString*newtitle;
```

In detailVC.m file

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:newtitle style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(back:)];
```

Comment: Based on your answer, I made some changes:
In postVC.m
    '//while call 2nd VC(detailVC)
    self.detailViewController.newtitle=self.title1;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];'
In detailVC.m
    'self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:newtitle style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(back:)];'
Please help edit your answer for me to accept it. Besides your code causes error but it doesn't matter because for me the idea is there. Thanks:-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a workout, although probably not the most efficient:

Create a property in your header file of PAWUserPostsDetailViewController

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *backButtonTitle;
```

Then go back into your view controller where you select the row and put this in didSelectItem method:

```
NSString *backTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@'s Posts",[userPassed username]];

PAWUserPostsDetailViewController *detailVC = [[PAWUserPostsDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PAWUserPostsDetailViewController" bundle:nil];;
detailVC.backButtonTitle = backTitle;
```

Then go back into your PAWUserPostsDetailViewController.m and set it as you normally would:

```
self.navigationItem.title = backButtonTitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

First try this:

```
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@'s Posts",[userPassed username]]; 

// If it`s to long try this:
    if ([title length] > 7)
{
    title = [title substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 6)];
}
self.title = title;
```

There isn't any reason to the first option doesn't work, but here a another option:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];

    if ([title length] > 7)
{
    title = [title substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 6)];
}
backButton.title = title;
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Becarfuly if title is to long, the name of the button will be back,